# fsteam cannot read data from file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm making a helper class for handling saving and reading data from a file. The writing function works properly, but It can't read and print the contents of the file. Here's the class:

```
class FileHandler {
private:
    fstream accountsData;

public:
    FileHandler() {
        accountsData.open("AccountData.dat", ios::in | ios::app);
        accountsData << "This is some intial data." << endl;
    }

    void loadDataFromFile() {
        if(accountsData.is_open()) {
            string line;
            while(getline(accountsData, line)) {
                cout << line << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    ~FileHandler() {
        cout << "Closing data file." << endl;
        accountsData.close();
    }
};
```

Writing works but reading doesn't. Please help.

Comment: I think the file pointer is set to end of file after you write, so when you read it's eof.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct line instead of line given in `FilHhandler constructor`:

```
accountsData.open("AccountData.dat", ios::in | ios::app | ios::out);
```